# Why is Spark running each task more than once

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[image: Spark application stages]

In my Spark application, I see the same task getting executed in multiple stages. But these statements have been defined only once in the code. Moreover, the same tasks in different stages are taking different times to execute. I understand that in case of loss of RDD, the task lineage is used to recompute the RDD. How can I find out if this the case, because the same phenomenon was seen in all the runs of this application. Can someone please explain what is happening here and under what conditions a task can get scheduled in multiple stages.

The code very much looks like the following:

```
val events = getEventsDF()
events.cache()

metricCounter.inc("scec", events.count())

val scEvents = events.filter(_.totalChunks == 1)
    .repartition(NUM_PARTITIONS, lit(col("eventId")))

val sortedEvents = events.filter(e => e.totalChunks > 1 && e.totalChunks <= maxNumberOfChunks)
    .map(PartitionUtil.createKeyValueTuple)
    .rdd
    .repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new EventDataPartitioner(NUM_PARTITIONS))

val largeEvents = events.filter(_.totalChunks > maxNumberOfChunks).count()

val mcEvents = sortedEvents.mapPartitionsWithIndex[CFEventLog](
    (index: Int, iter: Iterator[Tuple2]) => doSomething())

val mcEventsDF = session.sqlContext.createDataset[CFEventLog](mcEvents)

metricCounter.inc("mcec", mcEventsDF.count())

val currentDf = scEvents.unionByName(mcEventsDF)

val distinctDateHour = currentDf.select(col("eventDate"), col("eventHour"))
    .distinct
    .collect

val prevEventsDF = getAnotherDF(distinctDateHour)

val finalDf = currentDf.unionByName(prevEventsDF).dropDuplicates(Seq("eventId"))

finalDf
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .partitionBy("event_date", "event_hour")
      .saveAsTable("table")

val finalEventsCount = finalDf.count()
```

Is every `count()` action resulting in re-execution of the RDD transformation before the action?

Thanks,
Devj

Comment: what's your size of data on which you are running the job, How many node cluster you are running the job, Whether you have used parellelize method in your code.

Comment: Lack of caching? pls show coding.

Comment: @thebluephantom if this was due to lack of caching, why would the tasks be scheduled in different stages and want the execution time of the tasks similar? If you observe the attached image, you would see that there is a huge difference in the duration of the redundant tasks.

Comment: I could not see the coding so it could well have been a stab in the dark. I will look later tonight. Are the results correct though?

Comment: can u show all code?

Comment: curious to see expanded details

Comment: I think this question is similar to mine
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760644/spark-is-executing-every-single-action-two-times

Comment: interesting for sure

Comment: Not convinced on collect